# I want to get with conversion {eventName} using Japanese with Google Analytics Data API

Tags: google-analytics-api, google-analytics-4

Bad Requet is returned when trying to get conversion {eventName} using Japanese with Google Analytics Data API. Is it not possible to directly obtain the conversion of event names with multi-byte characters such as Japanese?

Bad Requet is returned when trying to get conversion {eventName} using Japanese with Google Analytics Data API.

Comment: Please edit your question and include your code.  Include what it is set to and the error you are getting.